# Water not rising in the flush/ rubber gasket does not create a good seal

Tags: toilet

The water in our toilet flush does not rise about the 20% mark.

[image]
[image]

More pics and videos: https://photos.app.goo.gl/xcuJ2dKajRQdbZ938

I figured out that the red rubber gasket doesn't stay in place. If I move the red gasket to its place and apply downwards pressure with my bards, the water does start to fill up. But as soon as we flush it, the gasket goes out of place as it is loose and isn't tied to anything.

Thanks for reading. Appreciate your help.

Comment: There are numerous videos on youtube that show how to replace the  gasket on a "Canister Style Flush Valve".

Comment: Agreed this is a simple repair you probably need a need a new seal.

Comment: Thanks. I just needed to put the existing seal in correctly. Flush is fine now. Youtube videos did help me understand the mechanism.